# Installing OS and always getting the White Screen of Death

Tags: windows

I am trying to reformat my Alienware M15x laptop which has a aftermarket graphics card installed (NVidea Geforce 675m).

No matter what OS I try to install, as soon as I get past the first part of the installation and it tries to actually start up the OS, the screen is white and I cannot do anything.

How can I fix this? I have an exam tomorrow and need this fixed before then!

Please any suggestions are fine,

Thanks

Comment: Do you have your old graphics card or is there one built into the laptop that you can use if you remove the aftermarket card? This would help you determine if the problem is the card or something else.

Comment: Through trial and error i found out the gpu is broken. I do have my old one and am just gonna sell the rig. Got myself a brand new m17x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GPU was fried, If anyone ever runs into this issue. Make sure to check your GPU as @Chris Kenst recommended.

After installing my previous GPU everything worked fine.